# Is there a way to set an exposure for a Poisson loss in Catboost?

Tags: poisson-regression, catboost

I'd like to use Catboost for actuarial models (eg claims frequency). Although I see that Poisson loss is an option, I don't see that exposures are directly supported. How do people deal with this?

Comment: Does Catboost provide a way to supply arbitrary custom instance weights? If so, you can work around the lack of offset/exposure support: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/270151/36229. Otherwise you might be stuck making a feature request. it seems like XGBoost and LightGBM do appear to support fully custom objective functions, if you need an alternative.

Comment: @shadowtalker I was recommended elsewhere to look into this functionality: https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboostclassifier_set_scale_and_bias

Comment: Seems reasonable, but it looks like you can only set a scalar `scale`, not a per-observation scale to act as the exposure.

Comment: @shadowtalker hmmm that's a problem then! Thanks for looking at it.